# Angular 6 Library Intellisense / Autocomplete

Tags: angular, typescript

How do I get typescript intellisense / autocomplete working for a simple Angular 6 library.

I have an Angular 6 project with an Angular 6 library. Typescript intellisense / autocomplete is working correctly on the project. However, it does not work when referencing library components. The library is NOT in npm and will only be used for this local project.

There's no mention of typings here (or anywhere else that I can find): https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-create-library

Have tried in latest versions of both VS Code and Visual Studio editors.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has resolved itself but I don't know exactly why. One or all of these factors helped resolve the issue:

1. Upgrade Angular. Currently using version: 6.1.1
2. Doing library production builds e.g. ng build --prod my-lib
3. Including my-lib in other projects using: npm install "../my-lib/dist/my-lib" (this auto creates a symlink).